# How to use android.util.Size so getters report non-zero?

Tags: java, android

I created a `android.util.Size`, but both `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` of the object return 0. Why is that? I expect the value from the getters to be the value I pass to the ctor.

```
@Test
public void testsize() {
    Size size = new Size(11,22);
    assertThat(size.getWidth(), is(11));
    assertThat(size.getHeight(), is(22));
}
```

`Junit` output:

> Expected: is <11>
> but: was <0>

Debugger says the object value (toString?) is "null" and when drill in: "Class has no fields".

`System.out.println` outputs "0" as well.

Working with `Android` API 30.

Comment: I think the issue is that Size is a platform class and therefore is a fake implementation when context is not a device; in a unit test.